# Lookup multiple criteria from column 2 in a table and return the value in column 1 if all match

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, xlookup, excel-2021

I'm essentially trying to lookup multiple items located in the data table in column 2 and return the corresponding order number from column 1 IF all the items match.

I was thinking I may have to utilise the xlookup function, and a few IFs, in conjunction with other functions - or it may only be achievable via VBA?

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated as I'm really not sure how to begin this one or what search terms to enter to try to find solutions and/or adivce.

Please let me know if I can provide anymore info to assist with this query.

**(Version: Office 2021)**

[image: Example]

Markdown version of data table:

| Order No. | Item | Qty | Order Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Apple | 2 | 30/01/2024 |
| 001 | Banana | 1 | 30/01/2024 |
| 001 | Pear | 1 | 30/01/2024 |
| 002 | Cherries | 4 | 02/02/2024 |
| 003 | Banana | 2 | 08/02/2024 |
| 004 | Apple | 3 | 15/02/2024 |
| 004 | Cherries | 5 | 15/02/2024 |
| 005 | Pear | 2 | 24/02/2024 |

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be there is more elegant way of doing this perhaps using a helper column to achieve the desired output for the version of Excel as mentioned in the OP: `Excel`<sup>**2021**</sup>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G3</kbd>

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A3:A10,TEXTJOIN("|",,INDEX(F3:F10,SEQUENCE(ROWS(F3:F10))))=E3:E10,""))
```

---

While the helper column formula is:

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",,FILTER(B$3:B$10,A$3:A$10=$A3))
```

---

[image]

---

**Edit:** 3/1/2024

As per new comments of OP:

> *I’ll be sure to study these functions as it will be useful for future*
> *projects :). As an optional extra, do you know of a way I can make it*
> *search for the items in no particular order? i.e. so entering “Banana,*
> *Pear and Apple” still brings up order 1? Currently I would have to*
> *enter “Apple, Banana & Pear” in that particular order as that’s the*
> *order they are in the table. I hope I have explained that correctly!*

---

[image]

---

Change in both of the formulas to ensure it work accordingly as per the given conditions. Additionally, it will also exclude duplicates for same order, if may arise.

• For Helper:

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",,SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(B$3:B$10,A$3:A$10=$A3,""))))
```

---

• For Matching Order:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A3:A10,TEXTJOIN("|",,SORT(UNIQUE(INDEX(F3:F10,SEQUENCE(ROWS(F3:F10))))))=E3:E10,""))
```

---

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you very much for your time and effort! Very elegant solution.

Comment: @itz_reecey ah thanks, its simple and easy to understand!

Comment: I’ll be sure to study these functions as it will be useful for future projects :). As an optional extra, do you know of a way I can make it search for the items in no particular order? i.e. so entering “Banana, Pear and Apple” still brings up order 1? Currently I would have to enter “Apple, Banana & Pear” in that particular order as that’s the order they are in the table. I hope I have explained that correctly!

Comment: @itz_reecey so you meant to say if its `Banana, Pear and Apple` then the order no is different is that correct? Or is it if the order is the like above it should bring up the order no 1 both can be done. I will show the latter one, which i think you might be looking for

Comment: @itz_reecey I have updated my answer, please let me know if that satisfies the conditions. thanks!